# Default Category Page not showing custom post type which has taxonomy category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy

I have created a custom post type 'Gallery' and assign Default 'category' of post taxonomy to this custom post type.

```
register_post_type( 
        'gallery', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Galleries',
                'singular_name' => 'Gallery',
                'add_new' => 'Add New Image Gallery',
                'add_new_item' => "Add New Gallery",
                'edit_item' => "Edit Gallery",
                'new_item' => "New Gallery",
                'view_item' => "View Gallery",
                'view_items' => "View Galleries",
                'search_items' => "Search Galleries",
                'not_found' => "No galleries found",
                'not_found_in_trash' => "No galleries found in trash",
                'all_items' => "All Image Galleries",
                'insert_into_item' => "Insert into Gallery",
                'uploaded_to_this_item' => "Uploaded to this Gallery",
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'hierarchical' => true, 
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'author','thumbnail','editor'),
            'rewrite' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
            'register_meta_box_cb' => array( $this, 'gallery_meta_boxes' )
        )
    );

    //register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'gallery' );
```

In backend add/edit Gallery post, its giving an option to to add/select category for that custom post but in frontend category page, this post is not displaying. Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default query doesn't include custom post types. You have to use pre_get_posts hook to modify your query. Hope this solves your issue

```
function custom_posttype_query( $query ) {
    if( (is_category() || is_tag()) && $query->is_archive() && empty( 
        $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
           'post', 'gallery'
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posttype_query' );
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, yes its working  but i added some extra condition for that post also who is using post category as taxonomy, so it will not affect that post also.

Comment: Can't understand what you wanna achieve...you want other post type added as well??

Comment: Thanks, i got my answer, i just added some extra condition for other custom post who is using same post category, so this will not replace theme. Thanks for help